# Adimensional goodness of fit to a straight horizontal line (f = constant)

Tags: goodness-of-fit, r-squared

I need to evaluate the goodness of fit of a set of data points (the measures) to a straight horizontal line / constant (the model). The ultimate goal is to evaluate the effectiveness of a noise equalisation method applied to an image, i.e. a method that transforms intensity-dependent noise to non-intensity-dependent (=constant) noise. I need to evaluate 'how constant/equalised' is the noise level in the processed image.

Among the methods available to my knowledge (e.g. norm of residuals (NoR), R-squared), I need a scale-invariant measure similar to R-square. The reason is that both data points and model depend on the histogram of the image, so they can vary from one image to another. A scale-invariant goodness of fit measure would allow me to compare the fits among different images from different datasets.

Unfortunately NoR and other similar 'sum-of-errors' measures are not scale-invariant. And R-square is not useful in this case (R-square = 0 when evaluating the fit to the mean value).

An example of such fit is given in the figure below.

[image: my plot]

Comment: Why would you wnt a constant moadel?  It doesn't tell you anything. It seems that you could fit a simple linear regression model and test that the slope is 0.  If you can't reject that null hypothesis you have some evidence that the constant model might be correct.

Comment: The constant model, in this application, is the perfectly intensity-equalised noise model, i.e. a noise that does not depend on intensity. I am working on a noise equalisation technique. Thus, I would need an adimensional measure that gives me the "goodness of noise equalization". One (but not the only one) possibility is a measure of goodness of the fit to a constant line. The 'slope 0' test is a good suggestion, even though it might be very sensitive to outliers (I have just 10 noise samples per image).

Comment: What about coefficient of variation (relative standard deviation) $\text{SD}[X]  \over \mathbb E[X]$?